# How to plot abs(sin(x)) with gnuplottex

Tags: gnuplot, gnuplottex

Here is my MWE. Why doesn't it reaches the x-axis?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
\begin{document}
    \begin{gnuplot}
        set terminal epslatex color  
        set xzeroaxis lt -1
        set yzeroaxis lt -1
        set grid xtics lc rgb '#555555' lw 1 lt 0
        set grid ytics lc rgb '#555555' lw 1 lt 0
        set yrange [-2:2]
        set xrange [-2*pi:2*pi]
        plot abs(sin(x))
    \end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: without having tested it, perhaps because the number of data points does not directly hit `y=0`. Might be an idea to increase the number of points. BTW: I'd guess you can plot this directly in LaTeX without needing GNUPlot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What happens is that gnuplot is sampling the x-axis. It means that it does not compute the function for all the possible points in the interval `[-2*pi:2*pi]` but only a finite number of points. The corresponding y-values are then linked together with a line to complete the plot. If the number of samples is too low you obtain a behaviour similar to yours. The best course of action is then to increase the number of samples considered by adding something like `set sample 1000` (tested with gnuplot but not with gnuplottex).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
\begin{document}
    \begin{gnuplot}
        set terminal epslatex color  
        set xzeroaxis lt -1
        set yzeroaxis lt -1
        set grid xtics lc rgb '#555555' lw 1 lt 0
        set grid ytics lc rgb '#555555' lw 1 lt 0
        set yrange [-2:2]
        set xrange [-2*pi:2*pi]
        set sample 1000
        plot abs(sin(x))
    \end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

In gnuplot with `set sample 100`:
[image: When sample is set to 100]

In gnuplot with `set sample 1000`:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just for laughs, here is straight LaTeX

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-2*pi,xmax=2*pi,
    ymin=0,ymax=1.1,
    ]
     \addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi,smooth,samples=1001] {abs(sin(deg(x)))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```